# Sinatra AWS SNS Endpoint - Help needed

Tags: sinatra, endpoint, amazon-sns

Hiya,
Due to the undocumented nature of the Amazon SNS endpoints and how they interact with the user, I am struggling to code an endpoint in Sinatra for my application.
I have some code written in PHP [here](https://github.com/lcarpenter/amazon-sns-http-php-endpoint), but I am struggling to convert it into a Ruby array because `request.env["rack.input"].read` encapsulates everything into something similar to a PHP array:

```
{"Message"=>"chapstick", "Subject"=>"cherry", "Signature"=>"QutYUXuqWQqiAY4PUvd+Hq+9KWSvPVwck22oV0pXkgSg0p+kZ/2Q+pS24siDPKxxHB8+ru5q6  QBqQv+RHKWobiLiupEf4UP1MQu3lnP4Z2TYWvbHVjNiO5OutcaivPrn08EIBTOMsWl2i8JmaTBXozOp4r1vheqg6k/wWDoUmd0=", "TopicArn"=>"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:687180262489:plinklebird", "SignatureVersion"=>"1", "Timestamp"=>"2010-12-03T22:10:01.141Z", "MessageId"=>"dc8a8502-44a8-41ec-9616-1d049f00724d", "UnsubscribeURL"=>"https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:687180262489:plinklebird:99e83fd5-58a9-41bb-82bd-9920a1ee1a94", "Type"=>"Notification"}
```

I am not sure how to handle this, can anybody please help?

Thank you very much for your time,
Luke Carpenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year and four months later, reflecting on this problem:

It was because I was a complete and utter noob, and I didn't know what a Hash was in Ruby at the time

In your `post` block, access the contents of the hash like so:

```
post "/" do
  puts params['Message']
  halt 200
end
```

The message SNS sends you will be printed out to STDOUT/your terminal

Comment: basically, use the name of the hash and this syntax: `hashname['Message']` to get the goodness out

If you need further help, don't hesitate to ask, ill write up a Sinatra example if you want?

Comment: It's a gist, I can't magically create the same gist with the same number